# Program blinking exit dots

Tags: python, loops, time, printing, newline

I'm trying to make a message that appears when exiting the program. What I want it to look like is like this:

  1. print the word "Quitting"

  2. repeat 3 times:
    - halt for 0.5 seconds
    - print a dot in  the same line with the word "Quitting"
  3. show the prompt in a new line

I wrote the code for it, But the problem is: either it shows the dots each 0.5 sec but vertically, or it waits for (0.5*3) sec to show everything (even the word "Quitting").

The code:

```
    print("Quitting", end='')
    for i in range(3):
        print('.', end='')
        time.sleep(0.5)
    print('\n')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does print with end='' doesn't appear until new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68444335/why-does-print-with-end-doesnt-appear-until-new-line)

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
import time

print("Quitting", end='', flush=True)
for i in range(3):
    print('.', end='', flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
print('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a duplicate, but code works if you do it like this:

```
import time

print("Quitting", end='')
for i in range(3):
    print('.', end='', flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
print('\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions guys. I just want to tell you that it's not a duplicate, because the one I wanted is with a "flush=True" on the first print function.